# Ruby On Rails - "undefined method `id' for 4:Fixnum"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixnum

I recently decided I wanted to list all the `users` in my Ruby On Rails application - since I couldn't figure out how to list them any other way, I decided to use partials.
I have the following on my administration page (just hooked up to a its own administration controller):

```
<%= render :partial => User.find(:all) %>
```

I then have a file called `_user.html.erb` in my users view folder. This contains the following:

```
<ul>
<% div_for @user.object_id do %>
    <li><%= link_to user.username, user.username %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

When the application runs and I go to the administration page, I get the following error:

> undefined method `id' for 4:Fixnum

It says it's because of this line (which is in the partial file):

```
<% div_for @user.object_id do %>
```

I'm unsure why this happens (and have googled for hours to try and find results and only find solutions that don't work for me). I think it's something to do with my usage of the `@user` instance variable, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get that error because `div_for` expects an active record object as an argument, which it calls the `id` method on. You pass in a fixnum (the result of `@user.object_id`), which is not an active record object and does not have an `id` method.

So pass in `@user` instead of `@user.object_id` and it will work.

Also you should use `user` instead of `@user`, rails 3 does not set instance variables for partials anymore.

Comment: Using @user I get the error: "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"

Comment: @Joesavage1: If you're using rails 3, you need to use `user` instead of `@user` (and if you aren't, you should use `user` anyway because that way it will work with any rails version).

Comment: Thanks so much! Using "user" instead of "@user" works a treat! :D

Answer (score 0):

Lose the .object_id part. I seriously can't think why are you using object_id!Do you have a good reason for doing so? Anyway div_for wraps a div around an object, so leave the .object_id part!

Comment: Using @user I get the error: "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"

Comment: The @user then is nil. Check your controller again to set the @user instance variable. I guess that you don't want the @user to be nil :)

Comment: Since it's the user partial - I assumed that it already knows what @user is. Since I want to loop through the users, surely it should already know what each @user is? If I need to add something in a controller - what controller (users, or administrate)

Comment: No, if you haven't defined the @user in your controller the view / partial can't (and shouldn't) guess the @user. Answer the following:
1. In what controller action your view is linked?
2. Are you using resources?
3. Have you tried render :partial => "your_partial", :object => @user ? This tells the partial with which object must render

Answer (score 0):

instead of object you are using it's column or visa varsa you are using at that time you will get this kind of error.

**Example**

I am using id instead of user = User.first object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
@item.unit_of_measure.name
```

instead of

```
@item.unit_of_measure_id.name
```